# iTunes freezes when syncing with iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, performance

I have a problem with iTunes (latest version) freezing when connected to my iPhone 5 (iOs 7.1.2) via USB. It connects with my elder MacBookPro, with that iTunes, but not on my iMac. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the cable since it connects very well with iPhoto so I guess something has been messed up in iTunes itself. What can I do to fix this, reinstall ITunes or is there any more easier fixes? I have reset the SyncServices but that didn't help and I have tried different cables too but the beach ball keeps coming back after each tryout (and freezes, not continues to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you [download](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) and install a fresh copy of iTunes and report back.

Before doing that, though, I suggest you create new user account on the iMac and see if iTunes hangs up when you plug in the phone. If there is no problem, then perhaps something is wrong with the iTunes preference files for your account.

Lastly, you might want to sign out of the iTunes Store (if you are currently logged in) and sign in again.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with another account on my iMac and a fresh iTunes there and it works, the iPhone appears and can be backed up etc so you might be up to something there, with the preference file. Which pref file is it and can it be deleted and will iTunes automatically make a new one? And how about all the playlist etc? Will it be lost?

Comment: It finally solved itself, with a lot of patience. Seems like my large amount of song titles where one of the problems. After a couple of hours of freezing iTunes suddenly started to play and after a couple of attempts to synchronize manually (music) it finally worked. But automatic synching can't be permitted!